# Assembling a var in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is looping in a timeout function. The nw remains undefined or is reset to undefined again at each new start. Why is that?

```
$("#wert"+i).load('variable.html #w'+i);
if(! nw){
alert(nw);
var nw = eval('neuerwert'+i); // Here I set the var nw, so why is it undefined again the next time around?
}
if ($("#w"+i).html() != nw){
wertaenderung('#wert'+i);
nw = $("#w"+i).html();
};
```

Comment: You need to put the variable declaration outside the function so it persists.

Comment: That's an answer (indeed, the correct one), more than a comment.

Comment: shouldn't all that code be in a callback function triggered by `.load` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `nw` has to be in the right scope:

```
var nw;
$("#wert"+i).load('variable.html #w'+i);
if(! nw){
    alert(nw);
    nw = eval('neuerwert'+i);
}
if ($("#w"+i).html() != nw){
    wertaenderung('#wert'+i);
    nw = $("#w"+i).html();
};
```

you USED the variable before you DECLARED it

Comment: is the OP supposed to play "spot the difference" ?

Comment: Javascript variables are not confined to if-statements. See function four in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Well, that makes sense but I want it to be undefined the first time around and not defined.

Answer (score 1):

try moving `nw` out of load function:

```
var nw;
$("#wert" + i).load('variable.html #w' + i);
if (!nw) {
    alert(nw);
    nw = eval('neuerwert' + i);
}
if ($("#w" + i).html() != nw) {
    wertaenderung('#wert' + i);
    nw = $("#w" + i).html();
};
```

Comment: it's not really global

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "var" in this line :

```
var nw = eval('neuerwert'+i);
```

So you will initialize the nw variable in the global context.

By writing var nw =  ... you create a local variable that is removed when you leave the  callback function.